# Azure Cognitive Search, get Document name for Download

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Cognitive Search, All Documents to index, and query. it is working quite well.

However, when a user finds a Document with the search term they would need to download it from a blob, Where do I get the Document Blob name, so I can create a URL. The Indexing Json just gives the Document Index ID, but this as far as I know not able to be used in a URL to downland the Document.  How do I find the Document referred to, and return it in a search.

Answer (score 2):

so when you Define your Index, you need to add these 2 Items

```
[JsonPropertyName("metadata_storage_name")]
 public string StorageName { get; set; }

    
[JsonPropertyName("metadata_storage_path")]
public string StoragePath { get; set; }
```

then also have these in your Serach query Result Structure. run the indexes and then you can get the document name and URL in the blob for download or action.