# Azure Cognitive Search - return full json as SearchDocument?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure.Search.Documents in C# to index JSON documents in Azure blob storage. About half of the fields of each json doc are meant to be searchable or fielded. The JSON also includes some fields that I don't want evaluated by my search.

My goal is to return the entire JSON document in my search results.

It seems like my choices are to (a) add SearchField records to my SearchIndex for every aspect of the document (in which the SearchDocument results are ready for me to use) or (b) leverage [metadata_storage_path / metadata_storage_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241697/azure-cognitive-search-get-document-name-for-download) and do a separate fetch for the document itself.

Option (b) feels less efficient, considering that the SearchDocument returned is already so close to the full JSON; it seems a shame to have to make a separate fetch for each document. But for option (a) to work, I'd need to tell the SearchIndex about the extra fields *without* them triggering false positive search results.

For (a) is there a way to add SearchFields (or the equivalent) and have them not trigger false positives? (IsSearchable seems to affect how, but not whether, they are evaluated). Also, if (b) is the better approach, is there a way to do this using "new SearchField" as opposed to declared via attributes? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked as “Retrievable” property of an index field attribute?

Comment: I think that's for whether or not the field should be allowed to get retrieved (I'm already returning all fields that are part of the index; I want the rest too). My concern in (a) is to avoid false-positive hits.

Comment: It looks like 'searchable' FALSE is probably what I need though. Trying now.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just needed to say IsSearchable FALSE. An oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197760/vince). Adding your comment as answer to help other community users.

> Set `IsSearchable` to `FALSE`